# Why is there a newline in the column after the multicolumn in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicol, multirow

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mycomment}[2]{\textcolor{red}{#1: #2}}
\newcommand{\tb}[1]{\mycomment{TB}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ma}[1]{\mycomment{MA}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sr}[1]{\mycomment{SR}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ta}[1]{\mycomment{TA}{#1}}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}

\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Dataset} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} & \\
    & O.B.R & A.R  
    & {Dataset2}\\
    \hline
    D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & D11 \\
    \hline
    D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & D21\\
    \hline
    D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & D31\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
   \caption{First subtable1}\label{tab:sub_first1}
\end{subtable}

\caption{Three simple tables} \label{tab:three_tables}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The resulting table is as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: Sample table]

**Why is the text "Dataset2" not same as "Dataset"?** Why is there a line break?

I tried to replace `{Dataset2}` with `\multirow{2}{*}{Dataset}`. However, it pushes the text even below as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

I am not sure where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the `\multirow` of the last column  in the first row, like the `\multirow` of the first column.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem, should starti with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bernard like I said in the question, multirow didn't solve the problem. I will attach the screenshot again.

Comment: You have to put `\multirow{2}{*}{Dataset2}` in the **first** row, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernard has already answered in his comment. However, since you have loaded `booktabs` and `siunitx`, use them and get rid of the vertical rules!

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mycomment}[2]{\textcolor{red}{#1: #2}}
\newcommand{\tb}[1]{\mycomment{TB}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ma}[1]{\mycomment{MA}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sr}[1]{\mycomment{SR}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ta}[1]{\mycomment{TA}{#1}}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cSSc}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{Dataset} &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{A (\%)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Dataset2} \\
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{O.B.R} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A.R}  
            & \\
            \midrule
            D1 & 2.1 & 2.1 & D11 \\
            D2 & 11.6 & 11.6 & D21\\
            D3 & 5.5 & 5.5 & D31\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{First subtable1}\label{tab:sub_first1}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Three simple tables} \label{tab:three_tables}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahaa! The mistake was I defined name of the Dataset2 column in the end (which is second row) :(

Comment: @kingmakerking Sometimes the trivial errors are the most difficult to find :):):) BTW, I have update my answer according to your updated MWE.

Comment: @kingmakerking: You can define name of Dataset2 in the second row, but in this case you have use `\multirow{-2}{*}{Dataset2}`.